# Making echo'ed text stay inside div

Tags: html, css

So im trying to make php echo'ed text stay inside a div. It's probably pretty simple, but I've been fighting with this for some time now.

So in the code below I echo a of a's, and now i want them to stay inside the div of 50px. Tried adding ***white-space: normal;*** to the div, but that didnt work out.

In advance, thanks

```
    <style>
.testDiv {
background-color: yellow;
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
}

</style>

<div class="testDiv">
<?php 

echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

?>

</div>
```

Comment: do you want it to wrap? truncate? or scroll - all doable with css

Comment: Yeah, i would like it to be wrapped inside the div. So when the text reaches the end of the div, it just 'breaks' to a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.testDiv {
    [...]
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.